# How to set every instance of certain variable in array to null and shift each variable to the left

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to create a method that sets every instance of the variable elt in an array to null, and then shift every variable after it to the left.  The current code that I have written only sets the first instance of the variable to null and shifts all other variable to the left, but does not set any other instance of elt to null.  The code I have so far is below.

```
public T remove(T elt) {
        boolean exist = false;

        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

            if (data[i] == elt) {
                data[i] = null;
                size--;
                exist = true;

                for (++i; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i-1] = data[i];
                }
            }
        }

        if (exist == true) 
            return elt;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

In main, I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bag<String> sbag = new Bag<String>();

        sbag.add("Noriko");
        sbag.add("hello"); 
        sbag.add("Buddy");
        sbag.add("Mary");
        sbag.add("Peter");
        sbag.add("hello");

        sbag.remove("hello");
```

When I print the array, I expect the following output:

Noriko
Buddy
Mary
Peter

Instead I get:

Noriko
Buddy
Mary
Peter
hello

This tells me it is only setting the first instance of elt to null, moving every variable to the left, and stopping.  Can anyone tell me how I can fix my code so that it sets every instance of the variable elt null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your innner and outer loop use the variable `i`. When the first match is found, the record is removed and `i` is incremented to `data.length` (when shifting the remaining records to the left). When you get back to the outer loop, `i = data.length` and the outer loop terminates.

You should use a different variable for your inner loop.

Comment: I would up-vote for the nice description of the problem, but the answer by dasblinkenlight fixes the (unstated) non-linear response time problem too.

Answer (score 4):

The common technique to the "remove all and shift" problem is to do it all in *one* loop with *two* separate indexes - one for reading, and one for writing:

```
int rd = 0, wr = 0;
while (rd != data.length) {
    if (data[rd] != elt) { // Shouldn't you use equals() instead?
        data[wr++] = data[rd++];
    } else {
        rd++;
    }
}
while (wr != data.length) {
    data[wr++] = null;
}
```

This technique is very useful in practice. I highly recommend working through an example or two with paper and pencil to make sure that you fully understand it.

Comment: Thank you!  This is very informative and teaches me a lot.  I really appreciate how this also fixes the non-linear response time issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your code it would seem like you would want to use a "List" type.

With this you can then add and remove variables without having to write an entire new function to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of excercise:

```
public T remove(T elt) {
    boolean exist = false;

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) { // changed data.length to size to avoid unnecessary iterations over deleted positions

        while (data[i] == elt) { // changed if to while
            data[i] = null;
            size--;
            exist = true;

            for (int j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) { // changed iteration variable, we don't want to move i
                data[j-1] = data[j];
            }
        }
    }

    if (exist == true) 
        return elt;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: I upvoted dasblinkenlight's solution though as I find it much better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I really appreciate your solution since it helps clarify the error in my original code.  I also really appreciate the solution from @dasblinkenlight as it taught me something new all together.  Just an interesting observation, the code did not work as you wrote it above.  As it is written above, it actually removed every item in the array.  I changed the while loop back to the if statement that I originally had in the OP, and now the code works exactly as I originally wanted.  The second for-loop you wrote though helped me a lot!

Comment: @Omar Interesting. Also, I think the code doesn't correctly delete the elements copied to the left (unless last element is actually a match), there should be `data[data.length - 1] = null` after the inner `for` cycle probably. You should check what it does when there are two "hello"s without anything in between, and what if the last element doesn't match `elt`.